# In Fortran, when in extension definition, how to set a public procedure into private?

Tags: fortran, private, procedure, public

Assume I first defined a type A in which a public procedure f is defined, and may also be bonded to A. In another module I have this type extended into B.  However, when I use type B, I do not want f to be exposed.
By the way, I don't want to use the submod technique.

complement:

Assume type(A) is already defined:

```
module mA 
type::A
 ...
 contains 
 procedure::f
endtype
endmodule
```

In another module B, we extend A as:

```
module mB 
use mA
type,extends(A)::B
 ...
endtype
endmodule
```

In this module, f may still be used. However, next, in module mC I will use(declare)

```
type(B)::Ob
```

and I wish "call Ob%f()" to be illegal. Or equivalently speaking, I want to ban some of the function when I extend a class.

Comment: Please show us an example code. Please do that always. Code illustration is always better than a lengthy description.

Comment: A possible workaround may be to just put "stop" statement in the "f" method in a child class? Another workaround may be to use composition rather than inheritance so that Ob%f() is not visible by construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to understand your descriiption, but if I understand it correctly it is not possible.

Consider you have a variable `class(A) :: o`. You are allowed to call

```
call o%f()
```

`class(A)` is polymorphic and can be any extended type of `A` so its dynamic type can be `type(B)`. So `B` MUST provide publicly accessible procedure `f` to stay compatible with the parent.