# How to design a PRIVATE OVERRIDABLE procedure in an abstract derived-type?

Tags: oop, fortran, private, abstract

Generally, abstract type is a model for descendant derived-types. Procedures contained in the type ought to be PUBLIC if it is deferred because a PRIVATE one can not be referenced or overridden out of the module itself. But how can I design the ABSTRACT derived-type if I want each and every one of the descendants to have a same functional PRIVATE procedure to do something (eg. To test the initialization status of it's instance)? Do I have to manually define them in each descendant or can I put a model in the ABSTRACT and implement it in the descendant?
Here's an example:

```
module test1
    implicit none

    private
    public :: my_numeric_type

    type, abstract :: my_numeric_type
    contains
        private
        procedure(op2), deferred :: add
        procedure(op2), deferred :: subtract
        generic, public :: operator(+) => add
        generic, public :: operator(-) => subtract
    end type my_numeric_type

    abstract interface
        function op2(a, b) result(r)
            import :: my_numeric_type
            class(my_numeric_type), intent(in) :: a, b
            class(my_numeric_type), allocatable :: r
        end function op2
    end interface
end module test1

module test2
    use test1, only: my_numeric_type
    implicit none

    type, extends(my_numeric_type) :: my_integer
        private
        integer :: value
    contains
    private
        procedure, public :: add => add_my_integer
        procedure, public :: subtract => subtract_my_integer
    end type my_integer

    contains

    function add_my_integer(a, b) result(r)
        class(my_integer),      intent(in)  :: a
        class(my_numeric_type), intent(in)  :: b
        class(my_numeric_type), allocatable :: r
        ! DO SOME ADDITION.
    end function add_my_integer

    function subtract_my_integer(a, b) result(r)
        class(my_integer),      intent(in)  :: a
        class(my_numeric_type), intent(in)  :: b
        class(my_numeric_type), allocatable :: r
        ! DO SOME SUBTRACTION.
    end function subtract_my_integer

end module test2
```

In the example, the descendant derived-type my_integer is a non-abstract type and inherits a deferred binding, so the procedures (add and subtract) must be overridden. But the procedures are defined private in my_numeric_type, that is to say they can not be overridden outside of module test1, so my_integer type above is invalid. What should I do ?

Comment: The thread has been renewed. Many thanks, @Vladimir.

Comment: I think this has a lot in common with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959048/in-fortran-when-in-extension-definition-how-to-set-a-public-procedure-into-pri/47959374#47959374 Can it be a duplicate?

Comment: @VladimirF, I don't see a connection between this question and that one.

Comment: @Vladimir, In the thread you suggest, type-bound procedurees in both derived-types are defined with default access that is PUBLIC. But the problem I have is to implement a PRIVATE deferred type-bound procedure.

Answer (score 0):

From the draft fortran 2018 standard, section 7.5.5, paragraph 9:

> A public type-bound procedure is accessible via any accessible object of the type. A private type-bound procedure is accessible only within the module containing the type definition, and within its descendants.

This means that it is possible to implement `private` `deferred` procedures, but only if the implemented procedure is declared in the same module as the deferred procedure.

For example:

```
module m
  implicit none
  
  type, abstract :: Parent
  contains
    procedure(add_Parent), deferred, private :: add
    generic, public :: operator(+) => add
  end type
  
  abstract interface
    function add_Parent(lhs,rhs) result(output)
      import :: Parent
      class(Parent), intent(in)  :: lhs
      class(Parent), intent(in)  :: rhs
      class(Parent), allocatable :: output
    end function
  end interface
  
  type, extends(Parent) :: Child
    integer :: contents
  contains
    procedure, private :: add => add_Child
  end type
  
contains

function add_Child(lhs,rhs) result(output)
  class(Child),  intent(in)  :: lhs
  class(Parent), intent(in)  :: rhs
  class(Parent), allocatable :: output
  
  select type(rhs); type is(Child)
    output = Child(lhs%contents+rhs%contents)
  end select
end function

end module

program p
  use m
  
  type(Child)                :: a,b
  class(Parent), allocatable :: c
  
  a = Child(3)
  b = Child(5)
  c = a+b
  
  select type(c); type is(Child)
    write(*,*) c%contents
  end select
end program
```

This constraint (that both `Parent` and `Child` must be declared in the same module) can lead to large files, and can cause problems with dependency ordering. There are a couple of ways to improve the situation:

- Use `submodules` to break the module up. e.g. `Parent` can have its own submodule, and each `Child` can have its own submodule.
- Rather than using `private` deferred procedures, use a naming convention for deferred procedures which should be treated as private, e.g. trailing underscores (so `add_Parent_` and `add_Child_`).